# How to hide NavBar when the user stops scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented a code in my website that will hide the navbar when scrolling down and show it when scrolling up.

the problem is I want when the user scroll up and stops scrolling to read something on the website after like 5 sec the navbar will hide again until the user starts scrolling again.

how can I do this?

this is the script I used for show/hide nav bar:

```
<script>
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const navHeight = 70;
// the point the scroll starts from (in px)
let lastScrollY = 0;
// how far to scroll (in px) before triggering
const delta = 10;

// function to run on scrolling
function scrolled() {
  let sy = window.scrollY;
  // only trigger if scrolled more than delta
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollY - sy) > delta) {
    // scroll down -> hide nav bar
    if (sy > lastScrollY && sy > navHeight) {
      nav.classList.add("nav-up");
    } 
    // scroll up -> show nav bar
    else if (sy < lastScrollY) {
      nav.classList.remove("nav-up");
    }
   // update current scroll point
   lastScrollY = sy 
  }
}

// Add event listener & debounce so not constantly checking for scroll
let didScroll = false;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    scrolled();
    didScroll = false;
   }
}, 250)

</script>
```

what can I add to it so the navbar will automatically hide when the user scrolls up and then stops scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const navHeight = 70;
// the point the scroll starts from (in px)
let lastScrollY = 0;
// how far to scroll (in px) before triggering
const delta = 10;
// the duration of inactivity after which the navbar will be hidden (in ms)
const hideDelay = 5000; // 5 seconds

let hideTimeout;

// function to hide the navbar
function hideNavbar() {
  nav.classList.add("nav-up");
}

// function to show the navbar
function showNavbar() {
  nav.classList.remove("nav-up");
}

// function to run on scrolling
function scrolled() {
  let sy = window.scrollY;
  // only trigger if scrolled more than delta
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollY - sy) > delta) {
    // scroll down -> hide nav bar
    if (sy > lastScrollY && sy > navHeight) {
      hideNavbar();
    } 
    // scroll up -> show nav bar
    else if (sy < lastScrollY) {
      showNavbar();
    }
    // update current scroll point
    lastScrollY = sy;

    // Clear the previous timeout if exists
    clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
    // Set a new timeout to hide the navbar after the specified duration of inactivity
    hideTimeout = setTimeout(hideNavbar, hideDelay);
  }
}

// Add event listener & debounce so not constantly checking for scroll
let didScroll = false;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    scrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

</script>
```

Comment: You can add a timer that will hide the navbar after a certain duration of inactivity from the user's scrolling. Hope that helps

Comment: `setInterval` should not be used for that specific problem.

Comment: @WaroodKhalid but you should not use setInterval anyways. It's a waste, and just not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `setTimeout` function with a 5000ms timer to hide the navbar. Then use an `addEventListener` to reset the timer if a scroll event within the window occurred:

```js
const NAV = document.querySelector('nav');

let timer = null;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (timer !== null) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    NAV.classList.add('d-block');
  }
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    NAV.classList.remove('d-block');
  }, 5000);
}, false);
```

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}


/* for demonstrationpurpose only */

body {
  min-height: 100000vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>THIS is the Navbar</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is pretty simple:

- Always hide the *nav* if:
  is distant from top **AND** user is scrolling down
- Hide *nav* after **5000ms** if:
  is distant from top **AND** user is scrolling up

Given the above logic *nav* will be visible when:

- is near the top (scrolled < ~70px or rather the nav's `clientHeight`)
- immediately on a scroll-up
- if mouse is hovering it (you forgot about that one?)

```js
const elNav = document.querySelector("#nav");
let lastScrollY = 0;
let scrollTimeout;

const toggleNav = () => {
  
  clearTimeout(scrollTimeout); // Clear on every scroll tick

  const isScrollDown = (lastScrollY - scrollY) < 0;
  const isDistant = scrollY > elNav.offsetHeight;
  lastScrollY = scrollY;
  
  elNav.classList.toggle("nav-up", isDistant && isScrollDown);
  
  if (isDistant && !isScrollDown) { 
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      elNav.classList.add("nav-up");
    }, 2000); // 2000 just to speed up things in this demo
  }
};

// Prevent hiding #nav if mouse is on it
elNav.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
});

toggleNav(); // Do on init
addEventListener("scroll", toggleNav, {passive: true}); // and on scroll
```

```css
* { margin: 0; }
body { min-height: 300vh; } /* Demo. To force scrollbars */

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: gold;
  transition: translate 0.5s;
}

#nav.nav-up {
  translate: 0 -100%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">NAVIGATION</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a timer that waits for some time after the user stops scrolling before hiding the navbar again:

```
<script>
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const navHeight = 70;
let lastScrollY = 0;
const delta = 10;
let didScroll = false;
let hideTimeout;

function scrolled() {
  let sy = window.scrollY;

  if (Math.abs(lastScrollY - sy) > delta) {
    if (sy > lastScrollY && sy > navHeight) {
      nav.classList.add("nav-up");
    } else if (sy < lastScrollY) {
      nav.classList.remove("nav-up");
    }

    lastScrollY = sy;
    resetHideTimeout(); // Reset the timer every time there's a scroll event
  }
}

function resetHideTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
  hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    nav.classList.add("nav-up");
  }, 5000); // Every 5 seconds
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    scrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

// Initial timer setup on page load
resetHideTimeout();

</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval` should not be used for that specific problem

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I have read your answer and I loved the way you've implemented it. Could you please elaborate on why you believe `setInterval` is not suitable in this particular context?

Comment: setIntervals are not meant to be left circling and cogging the main thread for no specific reason. Also, what is 250? A magic number? Callbacks are best handled immediately, not after a random *N-to-250* ms interval. Remove setInterval and you just got rid of the necessity to use the `didScroll` variable in the first place. PS: why would one want to `resetHideTimeout()` (hide the navigation) on page load without looking at the other needed parameters?

Answer (score -3):

The following snippet should do the trick.

```
    let element = document.querySelector("#yourElement");

    const onScrollStop = callback => {
    let isScrolling;
        window.addEventListener(
            'scroll',
            e => {
                element.style.display="unset"
            clearTimeout(isScrolling);
            isScrolling = setTimeout(() => {
                callback();
            }, 5000);
            },
            false
        );
    };
        onScrollStop(() => {
            element.style.display="none"
    });
```

Explanation: You want to add an eventlistener for scrolling the window, that sets a timeout of five seconds, before executing the onScrollStop function. Every time the user scrolls, we reset the timeout, because we want to wait five seconds, after the user STOPS scrolling, not when he stops for a just one or two seconds. If the condition (no scrolling for 5s) is met, we execute the onScrollStop function, which sets the display property of our header to none, making it disappear. Everytime the user scrolls, we set the header's display property to unset, to make it appear. again.

Hope this helps

Happy coding!

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low-quality. Please add a sufficient explanation.

Comment: Excuse me, my bad.

Comment: Avoid using `element.style.display` from JS. Use Element.classList instead.

Comment: This was just a demo, of course you wouldn't use element.style.display from JS. It's just a proof of concept. I could have used console.log too.

Comment: Not really helpful if it's a proof of concept though, is it?

Comment: Considering that my solution provides the functionality he asked for, and I don't know how he wants to implement the header's disappearing, I would say it's helpful enough @ethry