# Sticky navbar using relative position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a navbar with sticky. The idea is that, when the user scroll down, the navbar goes has relative position until the user scrolls up or when they reach the end of the webpage. I used javascript to add the sticky class during these two events. The problem I am facing is, since the navbar is being taken out of the document flow and having a fixed position- it is causing the entire webpage to shift up. To solve this I have added a pseudo element of same height that takes the place of navbar whenever sticky is activated. I want to know if this is the right way to solve this problem. Is this complicating the problem as I can solve this without a pseudo element just by using the position of my navbar as absolute. I am attaching part of my code for reference

```js
function scrollDetect() {
  const navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  const placeholder = document.querySelector(".navbar-placeholder");
  let lastScroll = 0;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    if (currentScroll > 0 && lastScroll <= currentScroll) {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      placeholder.style.display = "none"; // Hide the placeholder
    } else {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky", "z-index-999999");
      placeholder.style.display = "block"; // Show the placeholder to maintain space
    }

    lastScroll = currentScroll;

    if (currentScroll < 100) {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      placeholder.style.display = "none"; // Hide the placeholder
    }
  });
}

scrollDetect();
```

```css
  .navbar-placeholder {
  height: 4.5rem;
  display: none;
}

.main-navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  top: 3.4rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: red;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation: faceInEffect 0.3s;
  border-bottom: none;
}

@keyframes faceInEffect {
  from {
    top: -5rem;
  }
  to {
    top: 0rem;
  }
}

.content-for-scroll {
  position: relative;
  top: 100rem;
```

```html
<div class="navbar-placeholder"></div>
<div class="main-navbar" id="navbar">
  <a>hello</a>
</div>

<div class="content-for-scroll">
  <a>hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the reason for having the initial `top: 3.4rem;` on the navbar?

Comment: *"or when they reach the end of the webpage"* ? what should in that case happen? I think you missed to explained in a clear sentence the desired behavior.

Comment: the initial top is due to presence of other divs in my original code. The desired behaviour can be seen in the above code. If its not clear, the way I want it to be is- navbar should be visible when we reach end of the webpage or when the user scroll ups after the initial scroll down. I hope I made it clear now.

Comment: OK, I think I got it now. Added an example below. Let me know it it covers the desired behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Something terribly simple and really similar to the desired:
toggle *navigation bar* on scroll-down and always show navigation on scroll-up — consists in using position sticky for the navigation element, and control the `translate` property (for the Y axis) via JavaScript that basically toggles a `.is-hidden` class:

```js
const elNav = document.querySelector("#navbar");
let lastScrollY = 0;

const toggleNav = () => {
  const isScrollDown = (lastScrollY - scrollY) < 0;
  const isDistant = scrollY > elNav.offsetHeight;
  const isBottom = scrollY + innerHeight === document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  lastScrollY = scrollY;
  
  if (isBottom) {
    elNav.classList.remove("is-hidden");
  } else {
    elNav.classList.toggle("is-hidden", isDistant && isScrollDown);
  }
};

toggleNav(); // Do on init,
addEventListener("resize", toggleNav); // on resize,
addEventListener("scroll", toggleNav, {passive: true}); // and on scroll
```

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font: 2rem/1.4 sans-serif; }
nav, main, div { padding: 2rem; }

/* NAVIGATION BAR */

#navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: red;
  transition: translate 0.5s;
}

#navbar.is-hidden {
  translate: 0 -101%;
}
```

```html
<div>Some other DIV at the top of my page</div>

<nav id="navbar">Hello NAVBAR</nav>

<main>
  Hello. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati veritatis quaerat, cumque asperiores cum repudiandae vel minus, ab earum voluptatem. Possimus, adipisci laborum itaque perferendis reiciendis, impedit corrupti odio officia
  <div style="height: 200vh">...</div>
  End.
</main>
```

To change the trigger height point in which the navbar initially hides, change to i.e: `elNav.offsetHeight / 2` or any other value.

To conclude
the above example does not necessitates to set any static heights, to use any placeholders, and works pretty good on any website that needs to show the navigation as soon as the user starts to scroll up, with the addition to show the navigation bar at the far end (scrolled to bottom) — without much heavyweight coding.
For a similar solution, as reference see: [Hide nav bar when user stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76777900/383904)

Comment: hey @Roko, I am unable to move my navbar vertically when I use position as sticky. The reason I found for this is that I have a submenu in my header what uses position as fixed. I don't know for sure what is causing this but as soon as I remove the submenus position as fixed, I am able to move my navbar. Now, I can't change the submenus position style as my style needs it. Any idea how to solve this

Comment: Cannot say for sure without seeing the entire code that implies the workings of that navigation bar. Perhaps you should not use `fixed` for that submenu.

Comment: the idea for the submenu is that it is fixed at -1000px right (to make it invisible) until the user clicks on an anchor- then it will be right:0 (to become visible).  I will try to achieve this using some other way, thanks

Comment: @kangkong well, sorry for not being of further help on that matter. Happy coding!